# Diode. Послать больше одного action в circuit

Tags: frontend, scala, scala.js

Коллеги, не могу разобраться, как вызвать сразу 2 экшена из третьего экшена в `diode`. Вот участок кода из `App Circuit`:

```
val handler = new ActionHandler(myZoomedState) {
    override def handle = {
      case action => effectOnly(Effect(someFuture map {_ =>
        someAction  //Этот экшен не отрабатывает
        someOtherAction  //Этот отрабатывает
      }))

      case someAction => ???
      case someOtherAction => ???
    }
}
```

Как зачейнить их? Что-то вроде того, как мы делаем с колбэками:
 `someCallback >> someOtherCallback`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в том, чтоб создать третий экшен, комбинирующий эти 2 экшена. Плюс оно не ломает обработку ошибок футуры. Выглядит как-то так:

```
case object DoSmthStuff
...

val handler = new ActionHandler(myZoomedState) {
    override def handle = {
      case action => effectOnly(Effect(
          someFuture map { _ => DoSmthStuff } recover { ... }
      ))

      case DoSmthStuff = effectOnly(
          Effect.action(someAction) >> Effect.action(someOtherAction)
      )

      case someAction => ???
      case someOtherAction => ???
    }
}
```